# Create a network of blogs with WordPress 3

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a network of sites on the WordPress platform.  [Apartment Therapy](http://www.apartmenttherapy.com/) is a prime example of how I would like to implement the network. They are using unique domains, not subdomains or directories.

Click Technology in the top nav for Unplggd, click Children for Ohdeedoh, etc.

Can you give me your opinion of how to best do this with WordPress 3.0.x multisite?

I've read some posts about WordPress multisite that give me a hint but I want to build the architecture *right* the first time.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Maybe if you point all domains to one directory and rwerite it with this `multi.com` -> `primary-domain.com/multi` and build WP MU on subdirectories.

I'm not sure that could by done with mod_rewrite and I dont know WP MU so probably this wont work but there is always a little chance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

It might also be worth posting your question to [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) - which is a WP specific forum.